# Setting up Jetty/JDBC workspace

Tags: intellij-idea, jdbc, jetty

I am getting this error when setting up an existing workspace in IntelliJ.

I have setup the database, it exists in pgadmin3 and is searchable. It is set for localhost, port 5432.

```
2018-07-15 16:27:42.812:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:Scanner-1: Scanning elapsed time=629ms
2018-07-15 16:27:42.826:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Scanner-1: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@5796ab81{/,file:///Users/mihai-oprescu/Documents/witnex/witnex/target/Witnex/,UNAVAILABLE}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nothing to bind for name jdbc/witnex
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusDescriptorProcessor.bindEntry(PlusDescriptorProcessor.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusDescriptorProcessor.bindResourceRef(PlusDescriptorProcessor.java:836)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusDescriptorProcessor.visitResourceRef(PlusDescriptorProcessor.java:256)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
[2018-07-15 04:27:43,090] Artifact Witnex.com:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2018-07-15 04:27:43,090] Artifact Witnex.com:war exploded: Deploy took 3,117 milliseconds
```

In my context.xml, i have:

```
<New id="witnex" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg>
            <Ref id='wac' />
        </Arg>
        <Arg>jdbc/witnex</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource">
                <Set name="User">witnex</Set>
                <Set name="Password">XXXXXXX</Set>
                <Set name="DatabaseName">witnex</Set>
                <Set name="ServerName">localhost</Set>
                <Set name="PortNumber">5432</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
```

And my jetty configuration settings:

[image]

I am not quite sure how to set the jetty server to read the context.xml, perhaps that's the issue that I'm dealing with here.

Comment: Do you use any build tools (Maven/Gradle)? Dies it work fine outside IDE?